# Can't deserialize this JSON into C# object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have this JSON and would like to deserialize it into an object in C#. Notice the data field looks like a dictionary.

```
{
  "responseID": "LTg5MjUyNDgxMDgyNzU3NjgyNDMtMjAxNi0wNS0xOFQxOTo1ODoxOS45ODFaLTk4MTAwMDAwMA==",
  "timestamp": "2016-05-18T19:58:19.981Z",
  "type": "v0.1-reject-reason-codes",
  "context": {
    "tenant": "hpho"
  },
  "data": {
    "LOST_TO_COMPETITOR": "Lost to Competitor",
    "OTHER": "Other (see notes)",
    "DISCONTINUED": "Product Discontinued",
    "SERVICE_ISSUES": "Service Issues",
    "SEASONAL": "Seasonal Fluctuations"
  }
}
```

This is the class definition

```
public static class JSONConstants
    {
        public const string responseID = "responseID";
        public const string timestamp = "timestamp";
        public const string type = "type";
        public const string context = "context";
        public const string data = "data";
        public const string tenant = "tenant";
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RejectReasonCodesResponse
    {
        [DataMember(Name = JSONConstants.responseID)]
        public string ResponseID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = JSONConstants.timestamp)]
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = JSONConstants.type)]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = JSONConstants.context)]
        public SummaryContext Context { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = JSONConstants.data)]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SummaryContext
    {
        [DataMember(Name = JSONConstants.tenant)]
        public string Tenant { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how I deserialize it

```
string requestURL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK
                 && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NonAuthoritativeInformation)
                    throw new Exception(String.Format(
                        "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                        response.StatusCode,
                        response.StatusDescription));

                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RejectReasonCodesResponse));
                object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
```

However, the Data field in objResponse is empty. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify your class definition. I think it should look like this.

```
public class SummaryContext
{
    public string tenant { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string LOST_TO_COMPETITOR { get; set; }
    public string OTHER { get; set; }
    public string DISCONTINUED { get; set; }
    public string SERVICE_ISSUES { get; set; }
    public string SEASONAL { get; set; }
}

public class RejectReasonCodesResponse
{
    public string responseID { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Context context { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Different tenants have different dataset though. So those keys are not fixed strings.

Answer (score 0):

Rather try use [`javascriptserializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like

```
javascriptserializer js = new javascriptserializer();
var response = js.Deserialize<RejectReasonCodesResponse>(jsonstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly lint the JSON using a site like json.lint.  When its green go into visual studio if you have it and paste special, you can paste json as classes.  Website Json2csharp also useful.

Comment: Im not sure but using a different Json library may mean not having to have hints in your data models. Json.net and Service stack are 2 ive used.